# is it true that varnish cache mechanism can not be used with E-commerce website?

Tags: performance, optimization, varnish

I developing e-commerce website with Drupal and one of the problem with drupal is that its very slow so I found that varnish cache mechanism will help speed the website but when I started working on that then I came to know that it works on URL and does not work well with websites which has involved transactions so I am confused about using Varnish.

Can anybody tell that why to not use Varnish with E-commerce website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Edge Side Includes](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html) applied to Varnish. There is also the Drupal [ESI Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/esi) which works (but I have never used it in production).

Edge Side Caching will cache the full page (content/lists/views) in Varnish but you will be able to include dynamic parts (blocks).

This all depends on your developer expertise, the time you have to do the project, the project requirements (amount of static and dynamic parts) and the way you developed the project so far.

What I'm trying to say is: don't expect to do this just by installing a couple of magical modules ;)